# React-Native FlatList render some items slowly with large list

Tags: react-native

VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. {"contentLength": 2470, "dt": 2825, "prevDt": 2806}

how can i solve this probleme ?

```
 <FlatList
      ref={ref => this.chatFlatList = ref}
      data={this.state.messages1}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      onEndReached={ this.onRefresh}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.0001}
      inverted
      renderItem={this.renderChatList}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  
      />
```

Comment: If the state is changed frequently but does not affect the Flatlist, then you can use extraData prop. If you don't want to re-render your view, you can leverage shouldComponentUpdate() from the component life-cycle method.

Comment: You can try some of the recommendations here - https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large list and you want to render items smoothly you could give this library a try:
https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview

This is a high performance listview for React Native and Web with support for complex layouts.
Demo: https://snack.expo.io/@naqvitalha/rlv-demo